# Why is Chrome not setting cookie in production

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

I have an app in production, that sometimes sets a cookie in Chrome, and sometimes doesnt. Im using nodejs on backend. This doesnt happen in firefox, only Chrome. Am I doing something wrong?
Recently I added

```
    this.app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));
```

but it didnt help at all.

Code for setting cookie:

```
exports.oauthLogin = async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.query.token) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: "No token provided" });
  }

  const settings = await AppSettings.findOne();

  const response = await checkToken({
    token: req.query.token,
    serverUrl: settings.oauthServerUrl,
    clientId: settings.oauthClientId,
    clientSecret: settings.oauthClientSecret,
  });


  if (response.error) {
    return res.redirect("/");
  }

  const { _id, displayName, email } = response.user;

  let user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
  if (!user) {
    user = new User({
      displayName,
      email,
      oauthId: _id,
      accessLevel: "User",
    });
    await user.save();
  }

  const jwtUserData = {
    userId: user._id,
    userAccessLevel: user.accessLevel,
  };
  const token = jwt.sign(jwtUserData, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  res.cookie("token", token);
  return res.redirect(req.query.redirectUrl ? req.query.redirectUrl : "/");
};
```

Comment: cors will have nothing to do with it. Can you edit to include the code where you set the cookie on your HTTP response in node?

Comment: i updated the question with code. thanks

Comment: `jwt.sign` is async, are you sure `token` has a value?

Comment: its not async. i console.logged before and it does have value

Comment: as i said, the problem is only in chrome, this does work in firefox

Comment: something must be wrong with my chrome, cuz i just checked on my mobile chrome and it works

Comment: could my mac have been hacked?